# Should I subclass again or can I update a constraint on the fly?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints

I subclassed a UIView and set my constraints within this subclass.  Now In my view controller I'd like to update one of those constraints if a string value isn't present.  Should I just create a new subclass or is there a way I can update this constraint based on a value in the view controller not being present?

Comment: " I'd like to update one of those constraints if a string value isn't present". Please explain where the string value is and what constraint you want updated.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri the string value is set in the view controller which has a reference to the subclassed UIView.  The string shows within the referenced UIView.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should not create a new view for a constraint update , you should make the constraint as `IBOutlet` / instance variable in the class and deactivate it , then add the new one , or you can loop for the view's constraints and delete the constraint say with a pre-set identifier / it's attribute type ( width , height , leading ...etc )

Comment: The view I need to update is created programmatically as a subview within the subclassed UIView.  Therefore I don't see the view that needs updating in the storyboard.  If I'm following you correctly then I think you're saying I need to control drag from the view to the view controller which I can't do.

Comment: if you created it programmatically then make it an instance variable , so you can access it

Comment: what are you referring to when you say it?  Are you suggesting making the instance variable in the view controller or in the subclass?

Comment: make the subview an instance variable inside the class , so you can access it , or when you create the constraints make the one you wan to change an instance variable also inside the class  to update it